# Selecting only the top n values from grouped/sorted data

Tags: r, dplyr, grouping, ranking

I have a data frame with 4 groups (defined by categories "a" and "b" in column 1 and categories "X" and "Y" in column 2). I want to rank the attributes in column 3 by their values in column 4, but specifically within the groups in columns 1 and 2 (AX, AY, BX, BY), and then select only the top n (e.g., n = 2) values from each group.

`arrange(col1, col2, desc(col4))` works to arrange the data, but because the data are not technically grouped, functions like `top_n` return just the top n values of the entire list. I thought of using `slice_max` but can't install the beta version of dplyr from GitHub on my restricted network. What is the best approach?

Original data:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a       X       pat     1
b       Y       dog     2
b       X       leg     3
a       X       hog     4                   
b       Y       egg     5
a       Y       log     6
b       X       map     7
b       Y       ice     8
b       X       mat     9
a       Y       sat     10
```

`arrange(col1, col2, desc(col4))` gives

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
a       X       hog     4
a       X       pat     1
a       Y       sat     10
a       Y       log     6                   
b       X       mat     9
b       X       map     7
b       X       leg     3
b       Y       ice     8
b       Y       egg     5
b       Y       dog     2
```

but I cannot figure out how to filter this down to just the top 2 values.

(example input code below)

```
col1 <- c('a','b','b','a','b','a','b','b','b','a')
col2 <- c('X','Y','X','X','Y','Y','X','Y','X','Y')
col3 <- c('pat','dog','leg','hog','egg','log','map','ice','mat','sat')
col4 <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)

df <- data.frame(col1,col2,col3,col4)

colA <- c('a','a','a','a','b','b','b','b','b','b')
colB <- c('X','X','Y','Y','X','X','X','Y','Y','Y')
colC <- c('hog','pat','sat','log','mat','map','leg','ice','egg','dog')
colD <- c(4,1,10,6,9,7,3,8,5,2)

df1 <- data.frame(colA,colB,colC,colD)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `top_n` after grouping by the 'colA', 'colB'

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
     group_by(colA, colB) %>%
     top_n(2)
```